# Kotlin Android create and share CSV file

Tags: android, csv, kotlin, share

My android app create an csv file and share it immediately as the below code. The app start properly but there is no file attached when i select anyone of the application to share it. please kindly help to solve this issue.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val CSV_HEADER = "id,name,address,age"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        val qponFile = File.createTempFile("qpon", "csv")
        var fileWriter: FileWriter? = null

        try {
            fileWriter = FileWriter("qpon.csv")

            fileWriter.append(CSV_HEADER)
            fileWriter.append('\n')


                fileWriter.append("aaaaa")
                fileWriter.append(',')
                fileWriter.append("bbbbb")
                fileWriter.append(',')
                fileWriter.append("cccccc")
                fileWriter.append(',')
                fileWriter.append("dddddd")
                fileWriter.append('\n')

            println("Write CSV successfully!")

        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("Writing CSV error!")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }


        val sendIntent = Intent()
        sendIntent.action = Intent.ACTION_SEND
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, qponFile)
        sendIntent.type = "text/csv"
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SHARE"))

    }

}
```

Image1,the app start properly. 
[image]

Image2, no attachment
[image]

Answer (score 1):

After writing to the file you must close it:  
 `fileWriter.close()`  
and make this change: 
`sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(qponFile))`

Comment: i think it works. I guess I need to get permission because it shows permission denied. Could you please let me know what kind of permission I have to get?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />`
`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

Comment: These are permissions for the mail app. I don't think you need them

Comment: same ,  I tried email and whatsapp. it still doesn't work,

Comment: Maybe try to copy the file to external storage and attach it from there

Answer (score 0):

```
val HEADER = "Name, DateTime"

var filename = "export.csv"

var path = getExternalFilesDir(null)   //get file directory for this package
//(Android/data/.../files | ... is your app package)

//create fileOut object
var fileOut = File(path, filename)

//delete any file object with path and filename that already exists
fileOut.delete()

//create a new file
fileOut.createNewFile()

//append the header and a newline
fileOut.appendText(HEADER)
fileOut.appendText("\n")
// trying to append some data into csv file
fileOut.appendText("Haider, 12/01/2021")
fileOut.appendText("\n")


val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(fileOut))
sendIntent.type = "text/csv"
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "SHARE"))
```