# Kotlin - CSV file sharing request contains no data

Tags: android, csv, kotlin, email-attachments

for my app i'm attempting to create a csv file and share it via email/google drive.
however when i go to share the csv file, im am presented with the following "toast" . The code is located within a fragment.

```
upload was unsuccessful request contained no data
```

the following is my current code:

```
  val HEADER = "ID, Pa, m/s, Actual L/s, Design Pa, Design L/s, Design %"
        var fileName = "file://" + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Folder" + "/" + "mycsv.csv"
        println(" Debug: pressed   successfully!")


        var path = activity!!.getExternalFilesDir(null)   //get file directory for this package
        //(Android/data/.../files | ... is your app package)
        println(" Debug: path successfully!")
        //create fileOut object
        var fileOut = File(path, "mycsv.csv")
        println(" Debug: file   successfully!")
        //delete any file object with path and filename that already exists
        fileOut.delete()
        println(" Debug: deleted   successfully!")
        //create a new file
        fileOut.createNewFile()
        println(" Debug: file created  successfully!")
        //append the header and a newline
        fileOut.writeText(HEADER)
        fileOut.writeText("\n")
        // trying to append some data into csv file

        println(" Debug: csv written  successfully!")
        println("Debug:$fileOut")

        val sendIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, fileName)
        sendIntent.type = "text/csv"
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Share File"))

        println(" Debug: sent page open successfully!")
```

i have tried following similar questions asked on this site, however none of them were able to help as they were not in kotlin or i was unable to interpret it for my example. The attempt i have in this code is the closest i have gotten.

i have also tried:

```
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(FileName))
```

as it was a suggested answer for [Kotlin Android create and share CSV file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248872/kotlin-android-create-and-share-csv-file)

Would Anyone have any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Dont use Uri.fromFile(). Use a FileProvider to serve your file.

Comment: would this be the only change to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got it to work by first adding the following code into the **androidManifest.xml**
with in the  section.

```
 <provider
            android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
            android:authorities="com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME.provider"
            android:exported="false"
            android:grantUriPermissions="true">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
                android:resource="@xml/provider_paths" />
        </provider>
```

after this create an xml file in **res>xml>provider_paths***
inside the **provider_paths.xml** aded the following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <files-path
        name="files"
        path="."/>

    <external-path
        name="external_files"
        path="."/>
</paths>
```

finally to create the CSV file the code below was used inside the onClickListener.

```
  val csv_header = "ID, Pa, m/s, Actual L/s, DesignPa, Design L/s, Design %"

        var filename = "export.csv"

            var path = context!!.filesDir.absolutePath//get file directory for this package
//(Android/data/.../files | ... is your app package)
//create fileOut object
            var fileOut = File(path, filename)
//delete any file object with path and filename that already exists
            fileOut.delete()
//create a new file
            fileOut.createNewFile()
//append the header and a newline
            fileOut.appendText(csv_header)
            fileOut.appendText("\n")
// trying to append some data into csv file

                fileOut.appendText("$123")
                fileOut.appendText(",")
                fileOut.appendText("456")
              

        
            println("debug: Write CSV successfully!")

        if(fileOut.exists())
        try {
            val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context!!, BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider", fileOut)
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND)
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
            intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri)
            intent.type = "text/csv"
            intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share File"))
            println(" Debug1: sent page open successfully!")

        }catch (e: java.lang.Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            println("debug: failed")
        }
```